# JavaScript Google Chart Invalid Row #1

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-visualization

I am trying to create a google chart that has a list of all fixtures from a certain week and how many posts each one has.
This is the code I am running:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
      var stringArray = [];
      <c:forEach items="${posts}" var="post" varStatus="count">

        stringArray.push("<c:out value='${post.fixture.home.teamName}v${post.fixture.away.teamName}'/>", 1);
    </c:forEach>
    var newArray = [["Games", "Amount of Posts"]];
    var postArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
    var x = 1;
    while(x <= stringArray.length){
        var games = stringArray[x];
        var numbers = postArray[x];
        console.log("Game " + games);
        newArray.push([games, numbers]);
        x++;
    }
    console.log(newArray[1]);
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(newArray);

    var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'Referee Performance',
        subtitle: 'Season 20-21',
      },
      bars: 'horizontal'
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart_material'));

    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
  }
  </script>
```

Lets take a closer look at this section

```
        var newArray = [["Games", "Amount of Posts"]];
    var postArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
    var x = 1;
    while(x <= stringArray.length){
        var games = stringArray[x];
        var numbers = postArray[x];
        console.log("Game " + games);
        newArray.push([games, numbers]);
        x++;
    }
```

So the newArray is what will be used to draw the table because it has the headers, I then have an array with all the fixtures in (stringArray) and another array of how many posts each one has (postArray). I am trying to add the first index of string array and postArray to the next index in newArray. This isn't working and is doing something weird. I've added console.log and this is the output I am getting.

```
Game 1
2:50 Game Crystal PalacevSouthampton
2:50 Game 1
2:50 Game Crystal PalacevSouthampton
2:50 Game 1
2:50 Game undefined
2:54 (2) [1, 2]
```

So there is 2 problems with this. For some reason x isn't incrementing and it isn't saving the team Names its saving a 1 for some reason. I'm not sure if I'm doing something stupid or not?
So how can I fix the error above?
Thank you for your time

Comment: will you please share the output of the data from the console.log? for one, it appears there is only one column --> `"Games"` -- but two columns are required to draw a bar chart.

Comment: Ok, I'll work on adding some example data for the columns, and I'll get back to you

Comment: Right i've sorted it by adding mock data, thank you for your help. I didn't know 2 columns were needed for drawing